An interesting PDE for functionals
Define the functional $L(x,y,f(t))$ to be an expression with independent variables $x$ and $y$ and a function $f$. Some examples include $f\left(\frac{x+y}2\right), 2f(x)+f(y), \int_y^xf(t)dt$. Consider the PDE $$L_x(x,y,f)+L_y(x,y,f)=L(x,y,f')$$. What I want to do is find solutions to this PDE. Here we want $L$ to depend on $x,y$ and $f$ so things like $L(x,y,f)=x,f(x),f(y),x+y$ and other similar expressions aren't allowed. I found two solutions so far, namely $L=f\left(\frac{x+y}2\right)$ and $L=\sum_{k=y}^xf(k)$. I couldn't come up with any other solutions. Something like $L=\int_y^xf(t)dt$ is a sum in disguise ($\int_y^xf(t)dt=\sum_{k=y}^{x-1}\int_k^{k+1}f(t)dt$) so it doesn't count. Same thing with $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)f\left(\frac{x+y}2\right)$, it can be written in the form $L=g\left(\frac{x+y}2\right)$. Any idea?
